# How to deploy a sandboxed Event Receiver to SharePoint 2010 Foundation?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-handlers, deployment

I am working on a test environment where is installed Windows Server 2008 R2, SharePoint Foundation 2010 and Visual Studio 2010.

I have developed and debugged a new Event Receiver for a Document List using a solution configured as "sandboxed solution".

Now I am ready to deploy my custom Event Receiver, but how? Do you known a guide or a list of steps compatible with this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have packaged your solution as James has stated you will find the resulting WSP file in the relevant folder (Release or Debug) in the \bin folder within your project structure.

This is the file which needs to be uploaded to the solution gallery within your target site collection.  Once it is uploaded into this gallery use the ribbon to activate it, then just check that your features are activated.  Web scoped features will need to be activated via the UI.

That should be all that is required.

Comment: Thank you both, I did it! :) This is a very nice feature of SharePoint 2010. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010 you should just be able to right click the project in the solution explorer and click "Package", and deploy the resulting WSP file to your live environment.

If you are testing your solution, pressing F5 should deploy it straight into your development environment for testing.